# Can someone help me design this shape in TikZ

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, physics

[image]

I've gotten a little bit done so far but I'm not sure how to do it. Especially because I don't quite know how to do the coordinate system yet. The lower cylinder has an arrow pointing at it designating that its radius is 5.1 CM btw.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (16,10);

  \node [ anchor=south west, minimum width=20,minimum height=10] (Response) at (0,0) {};


\draw [draw=black, very thick] (0,8) rectangle (8,10);
\draw [draw=red, dashed, very thick] (3,8) rectangle (5,5);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

I really don't understand the cordinate system. How can I better understand it?

Comment: Well, you copied this fragment from an answer you received to your previous question. Wouldn't it make sense to try to understand the previous answer, accept it if it is useful, and apply the knowledge gained on this one?

Comment: I'm really having trouble understanding how to do it.

Comment: But you would be so much better off if you tried at least to understand the answer you got. Then you would not depend on others. Also it would be great if you could accept it if it answered the other question.

Comment: I did some edits but I'm still struggling.

Comment: I did a lot more work on it. But i'm still not sure what I'm doing.

Comment: You say *I really don't understand the cordinate system.*. It is cartesian one. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: I understand the cartesian plane, what I don't understand is where on the page certain coordinates are or what the increments are. If I knew where 0,0 was and what the increments were then I would be better able to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I really think it would be better if you asked small conceptual questions so that you can do these things yourself. The hardest part is to decipher stuff from a screen shot (and quite likely I misread some).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,quotes,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[m/.style={draw,minimum size=1.5em,label=right:$m$}]
 \node[minimum width=9em,minimum height=3em,draw] (M) {$M=\SI{4.58}{\kilo\gram}$};
 \draw[|-|] ([yshift=2ex]M.north west) -- node[fill=white]{$2R=\SI{27.5}{\centi\meter}$} 
    ([yshift=2ex]M.north east);
 \node[minimum width=2em,minimum height=3em,
  path picture={
  \draw[decoration={waves,radius=2em,segment length=3pt,pre length=0pt},decorate]
    ([yshift=2em]path picture bounding box.north) -- (path picture bounding box.south);
  \draw ([xshift=\pgflinewidth/2]path picture bounding box.north west)
   -- ([xshift=\pgflinewidth/2,yshift=3pt]path picture bounding box.south west)
   ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth/2]path picture bounding box.north east) --
   ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth/2,yshift=3pt]path picture bounding box.south east);
    },below,label={[right]30:{$2r=\SI{5.1}{\centi\meter}$}}] (S) at (M.south){};
 \draw ([xshift=0.5ex]S.south) |- ++ (-4em,-1ex) |- ++ (1ex,-1ex) -- ++ (0,1ex)
 ([xshift=-0.5ex]S.south) |- ++ (4em,-1ex) |- ++ (-1ex,-1ex) -- ++ (0,1ex);
 \node[circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em,right=8em of S.south east] (C){};
 \node[m,below=5em of C.east] (m1){};
 \node[m,below=5em of m1] (m2){};
 \draw[semithick] (m1) -- (C.east) arc[start angle=0,end
    angle=90,radius=0.75em+0.5\pgflinewidth] --([yshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]C.north-|S.east);
 \path[semithick,-Triangle,pos=0.9]
  ([yshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]C.north) edge ++ (-1,0)
  (m1.center) edge["$T$"'] ++ (0,1)
  (m1.center) edge["$m\,g$"] ++ (0,-1)
  (m2.center) edge ++ (0,1)
  (m2.center) edge ++ (0,-1);
 \draw[|-|] ([xshift=-3em]m1.west) -- node[fill=white]
 {$h=\SI{0.94}{\centi\meter}$} ([xshift=-3em]m2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the future I'd recommend that you perform a [visual search](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8522/194703) and start with a similar looking diagram, there are plenty. And if you have problems with some parts of the codes, this will define a clear question that will be better received as long as you make an effort in posting a complete example (as opposed to fragments) and clearly indicate which part causes problems.

Comment: I'm getting an issue where it's not including the units next to it. How do I add those? It's saying there's an undefined control sequence.

Comment: @PangolinCough2020 Most likely you forgot to add `\usepackage{siunitx}`.

Comment: Yes, That was the issue. Thank you. I also want to try to add the label on the lower cyleder. Can you give me a hint as to what the wording for that would be?

Comment: @PangolinCough2020 This can be done with `label` as in all the other nodes. Please really start asking simple questions about how to do such things in form of real questions, not in comments.